# Travel with a photography/camera backpack

Tags: luggage, backpacks

I am m/29 and am about to leave for two weeks backpacking trip to Europe (abt 4-5 cities).

I have a camera backpack (lowepro fastpack 250 aw ii - http://store.lowepro.com/fastpack-bp-250-aw-ii). Now considering this backpack that I already have, I want to know which second back I should be choosing for my cloths. When it comes to cloths, I can pack light but will be still caring stuff which can fit inside a 25-30l bag..

Below are three options I have for second bag:

**(1) Rolling/Spinner suitcase:** I have a Samsonite Spinner 21 rolling suitcase. Its usually bigger that what I want for my cloths. I can also accommodate my camera backpack inside this suitcase in addition to my cloths. But still this is a rolling suitcase and I have heard that traveling in European cities/trains with rolling suitcase might not be good idea.. 
I can also take this rolling back as carry-on and avoid checking in.

**(2) 55l/65l backpack:** I can get a bigger backpack, and accommodate my existing camera backpack inside this bigger backpack in addition to cloths. I have never seen or heard anyone packing like this - especially considering size of my camera backpack. But with this option, I might need to check-in my bigger backpack as this will be bigger than carry-on size.

**(3) Duffel bag:** I can get a medium size Duffel bag just for my cloths. This can be bit light weight. But I do have to always carry this which might be inconvenient and my one hand will be occupied always..

Can anyone please share experience and suggest me what will be best choice that I can make here..

Thanks !!

Comment: Have you thought about a duffel with a shoulder strap? That will allow you to carry it as if it was a messenger bag, but bigger. You will need to test it with your backpack as not all combinations work well.

Comment: Thanks for response !!
Yes duffel bag that I am thinking will be with a shoulder strap only.. But your point is correct.. I have to test with my backpack as it may be bit cumbersome while walking around train stations. That will be also lightweight when compared to roller suitcase..

Comment: Not sure this is answerable in a general sense, as what works for you depends on your exact needs. And your destinations. Southern Europe? Less clothes needed. Summer? Even less. I'd suggest to let your choice depend on how you could re-use your second bag after this trip.

Comment: Any reason in particular you think travelling with a roller suitcase in Europe is a bad idea? I can't say I've ever had a problem - especially with small, carry-on sized bags (given it's that small, you'll be able to carry it up and down stairs or short rough terrain, I assume)